# SSRS Nested Tablix dynamically increase/decrease row height

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have a report that requires showing repeated objects (with different data) on each new page depending on the number of results returned in a query. The objects on each result page include a range of different tablix in different positions.

**Context**

To achieve the above requirements, I first created the separate tablix required for a page.

[image: Separate tablix created]

Then, to apply the correct positioning I nested the separate tablix into another with the appropriate rows and columns to allow for the required size.

[image: Placed separate tablix into a tablix to apply positions]

Finally, in order to repeat the page per result, I created a final table with one cell and fit them all in and added the group to that cell. This did manage to work and I get a page per result as required.

[image: Placed positional tablix into outer tablix to apply grouping]

**The problem**

The issue I am having, however, is that some of the separate nested tablix have their own groups and depending on the data will add extra rows. My outer tablix with one cell seems to just have a fixed size so I am unable to see extra data in my nested tablix. This is also happening when I dynamically hide a row in one of the nested tablix, it doesn't seem to decrease the overall size of the outer tablix. Is there something I am missing? Also if there is a simpler way to carry out my requirements I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is simply impossible with nested tables.  Are you trying to output many different bills across different meters from within the same SSRS report?  If so, you should parameterise your report and set up a data driven subscription to export different files for each.

Comment: @iamdave I already have parameters set up that contain an XML for each separate bill. It's just that in some instances, one bill will have multiple meters and have the requirement mentioned in the question. So do you think what I am trying to achieve is not possible in SSRS?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just over complicating things.  For example, why is your parameter taking in XML?  Why not just an Account Number that is then referenced in the database query?

That aside, you just need a Tablix Group by `Meter`, within that all the necessary fields for each meter and a Details Group that will expand to show each line item against each meter.

You should be able to set this up with a Page Break set after each `Meter` group to push the next meter onto the next page.

If you need all the Address bits included for each Meter, just include them within the Meter Group and they will all get replicated.

There is no need for nested tables here.

Comment: So the data comes through as XML from our bill event provider so I am unable to go directly into the database. I already have my outer tablix grouped by the meter and page break on a new instance of the group. If I only have one tablix grouped by meter, how will I get the correct sizing on each page on for example the "S" box which has different column widths?

Comment: You don't need an 'inner' and 'outer' tablix, just use nested groups within a single tablix.  Regarding column widths, they are fixed in all scenarios.  No way to dynamically change them in SSRS.